# How to regex replace in PhpStorm

Tags: regex, phpstorm

I am new to regex for PhpStorm.

I have below text format:

```
{{ HTML::style('assets/css/jQuery.ui.css') }}
```

I need to replace it by:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Bust::url('assets/css/jQuery.ui.css')">
```

What regex can I use? See the image below:

[image]

Comment: [A regex like `\{\{ HTML::style\(([^\)]+)\) \}\}` should work](https://regex101.com/r/k22Ca2/1). Your main issue is that `{` and `}` have special meaning in regex and need to be escaped.

Comment: @h2ooooooo in Phpstrom it not replace with string it gives `<link rel="stylesheet" href="Bust::url('1')">`

Comment: I believe in PHPStorm you have to use `$1` rather than `\1` in the replacement

Comment: its working with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ Bust::url($1)}}">` Thanks @h2ooooooo

Comment: Glad you got it working :)